# What causes Bamboo to fail at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so)

Tags: java, war, bamboo

Here's what my error log shows:

```
/WEB-INF/lib/jetty-http-7.2.1.v20101111.jar,file:webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jetty-io-7.2
.1.v20101111.jar,file:webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jetty-jndi-7.2.1.v20101111.jar,file:web
app/WEB-INF/lib/jetty-plus-7.2.1.v20101111.jar,file:webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jetty-sec
urity-7.2.1.v20101111.jar,file:webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jetty-server-7.2.1.v20101111.j
ar,file:webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jetty-servlet-7.2.1.v20101111.jar,file:webapp/WEB-INF
/lib/jetty-util-7.2.1.v20101111.jar,file:webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jetty-webapp-7.2.1.v
20101111.jar,file:webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jetty-xml-7.2.1-atlassian-3.jar,file:webapp
/WEB-INF/lib/mail-1.4.1.jar,file:./], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoade
r{urls=[], parent=null}}
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
...
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   ...1 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by the server losing it's default route to the internet.  For some reason Bamboo requires internet access (license check?).

While diagnosing the problem I discovered that the default route was missing and when I restored the default route bamboo started running again.